# Javascript, advancing date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I using a date-picker to set a start and end date. The date range is supposed to move forward each day for a two week, sliding window of entry.

My code below works but I would like to refactor it into something that is easier to maintain. What techniques or tools can I use to improve this code?

```
var challenge_start = new Date(2015,04,04);
var challenge_end = new Date(2015,06,12);
var range_start;
var range_end;
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(today<challenge_start) {
    range_start=challenge_start;
    range_end=challenge_start;
}
else if(today>challenge_start && today<challenge_end) {
    if(mm==5) {
        if(dd<18) {
            range_start=challenge_start;
            range_end=today;
        }
        else {
            range_start=today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);
            range_end=today;            
        }
    }
    else if(mm=6) {
        if(dd<29) {
            range_start=today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);
            range_end=today;                
        }
        else {
            range_start=today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);
            range_end=challenge_end;                
        }
    }
    else if(mm==7) {
        if(dd<12) {
            range_start=today.setDate(today.getDate()-14);
            range_end=challenge_end;                
        }
        else {
            range_start=challenge_end;
            range_end=challenge_end;                
        }
    }
}
else if(today>challenge_end) {
    range_start=challenge_end;
    range_end=challenge_end;        
}

$("#date").datepicker({
    startDate: range_start,
    endDate: range_end,
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    language: langdate,
    disableTouchKeyboard: true
});
```

Comment: How is it failing for you? What is it doing / failing to do?

Comment: Thanks for looking. I guess I'm just looking for a more efficient way to do this. Something easier to change/manage when the start and end dates are different.

Comment: You may want to look at moment.js; it simplifies dealing with dates and includes (for instance) a method for 'add one week'.

Comment: More precise in what the author is asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not understand what you are striving for, but I'm pretty sure you don't need to have those `if(mm==x)` and `if(dd=x)` statements.

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
var challenge_start = new Date(2015,04,04);
var challenge_end = new Date(2015,06,12);

function getDatePlusDays(origDate, days) {
    var date = new Date(origDate.getTime());
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}

function getClosestDateInRange(startDate, endDate, date) {
    return (date < startDate) ?  startDate
            : ((date > endDate) ? endDate: date);
}

var today = new Date();
var range_start = getClosestDateInRange(challenge_start, challenge_end, getDatePlusDays(today, -14));
var range_end = getClosestDateInRange(challenge_start, challenge_end, today);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n09asc92/1/)

Comment: Thanks. This helps! The sliding entry window is backward in time so a quick switch should do it.

Comment: A user can't make an entry beyond today ... but can make an entry for up to 14 days prior.

Comment: @user1964234 - Is it correct now? Or should that be `-13`, so it is a two week period?